# Every field can have multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, erd

I am asked to allow users to input multiple values in EVERY field. So the option is limitless.

For example. Columns are:
CompanyID-
Company name
Website
Key_Markets
M&A_History
Highlights
Region
Comments

A scenario is a company can have multiple websites,key markets, region, etch. How would I do this professionally? I am thinking of putting every column a seperate table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Start by correctly tagging your question, is either mysql or sql server 2008R2, not both. On this particular case, as you are asking about your possible database design, maybe is not so important, but you should follow this rule. Then you may read about relational databases design. You could start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design).

Comment: A normalized database will suffice.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are three ways to realize this.

1) Write multiple fields into one column seperately. This would be a very bad design and you would have to handle the splitting in your application - Do not do that ;-)

2) Use one table with multiple groups to store the data. This would make sense for parameters but not really if you have different values for each customer. For example:

- CompanyID
- GroupID
- Position
- Value

Example:

```
108001, 'homepage', 1, 'www.mypage.com';
108001, 'homepage', 2, 'www.mysecondpage.com';
108001, 'homepage', 3, 'www.anotherpage.com';
108001, 'markets', 1, 'erp';
108001, 'markets', 2, 'software';
108001, 'region', 1, 'germany';
108001, 'region', 2, 'austria';
108001, 'region', 3, 'poland';
```

3) Use seperate tables for each 1:n relation! This would be the best solution for your needs I guess. This would have the advantage that you can easily extend your schema and store more data in it. For example if you decide to store the amount of users for each region or key markets etc.

**Another point:** Use n:m relations to avoid double content in your database! For example should the key-markets and regions be stored in a completely seperated table and you store the IDs of the customer and the key-market in a crosstab. So you do not need to store the key-markets as a string for each customer!

Comment: @Mag Ron - Re: Point (1) above:  **Do not do that!**  Dustin said it and I support that statement.  Combining values in a single field also begs questions like: How many values are allowed?  How do you tell them apart, e.g. telephone numbers (Home, work, mobile, facsimile, next of kin, ... .)?  Does the maximum combined length start running into maximum row size limitations?  Just don't go there.

Comment: I appreciate all the help.

Comment: I am doing this. I placed the columns into their own tables. Right now I have around 30 tables. However, I am receiving an error because there is a limit how much I can index company_id.

Comment: Though, I getting around it by not enforcing referencial integrity.

Comment: Since the columns are not in a relationship with each other.  I having problem concating them with each other. For example Select Company_Name, Website is fine. But if I do Company_Name,Website,History together, it only displays companies with website "AND" History. I need to create null values in History to able to display it properly.

Comment: You don't need to do it if you use for example a left outer join. These kind of joins will join data even if there are missing values. The missing values will be filled with NULL values. Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

You would need a database structure like:

```
table_master_companies
   - record_id
   - company_name

table_websites
   - record_id
   - company_id
   - website_address

table_key_markets
   - record_id
   - company_id
   - key_market
```

etc. You would then need to use joins to concat all the information into a single recordset.

Comment: I would suggest to store the key markets in a crosstab, so you can avoid redundancy in your database by assigning just their IDs to the company IDs.

Comment: @dustinklien completely agree, mistake on my part!